# Error instantiating MongoDate inside PHP class Method MongoDate::__toString() must not throw an exception in

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following code to create a custom Class working with Mongo

```
class MongoHandler{
    protected $col = NULL;
    protected $db;
    protected $timestamp;

    public function __construct($db_version) {
        // opening db connection
        $db = new MongoConnection();
        $this->db = $db->getMongoCon($db_version);
        $this->timestamp = new MongoDate();
    }
}
```

However $this->timestamp = new MongoDate() generated the error below:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Method MongoDate::__toString() must not
>   throw an exception in"

I want to use this timestamp in all the methods I interact with mongo (insert/update).

Comment: You need to catch the exception to find what is wrong. Extend `MongoDate` and override `__toString()` method, catching the exception there. Then log, or simply `return $e->getMessage()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add mongo php extension to your php.ini:

```
  extension=mongo.so
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the problem here. PHP would be complaining about MongoDate not existing at all if that were the case. (That, and the user would probably have run into problems much earlier…)

Comment: That's the exact case i had yesterday, and it did solved my problem